# Are "5" and "4x" algebraic expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In an elementary textbook I have, an algebraic expression is defined as

> The expressions in which the numbers, or variables, or both, are
>   **connected by operational signs** (+, - etc.) are called algebraic expressions.
>
> For example $5$, $4x$, $a+b$, $x-y$ etc.

The question is that how is $5$ or $4x$ an algebraic expression when it does not have any operational sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. It's due to what I like to call "the invisible plus sign."

We're *really* talking about $+5$ and $+4x$.

You need to aware of the invisible plus sign when you manipulate an expression algebraically.

For example, solve for $x$:

$$5+4x=0$$

The first step is to move the $+5$ to the right hand side of the equation. When you do so, *it changes signs*.

$$4x=0-5=-5$$

(The fact that it's sign becomes opposite means that it *has* a sign.)

Note that when those terms are part of a larger expression, only the initial term has an "invisible" plus sign. The "$+$" on front of $4x$ is quite apparent.

Comment: Good answer! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

$5=5+0$, $4x=4x+0$. In reality, they ***have*** an operational sign. 
Or $5=5+7-7$ or $4x=4x+6-6$.

Comment: Let's not forget that $4x = 4 \cdot x$.

Comment: Yea. As multiplication is an operation, addition is also an operation. And this was the first thing that came to my mind so...